# Uniform number formatting

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I am facing the problem that in a collaborative research paper there are several different number formats within the text, if the number is not pasted in math mode.

For example: `10.000,00` or `10,000.00` or `10000` or `10000,00`

I am looking for a solution, where I can wrap a function around a number and it is formatted in the whole document in the same way.

Comment: `siunitx` comes with a `\num` macro that does this and many other goodies

Comment: Does the answer below solve your question?

Answer (score 8):

There is: `\num` from `siunitx` or `\numprint` from the paronymous package. Both work in tables (alignment of the decimal part symbol), are language-aware and highly customisable. You can have automatic rounding of numbers to a fixed number of decimals, a convenient way of typing numbers in scientific notation (6.022141e23 will produce a correct formatting of the Avogadro constant), thousand and thousandth separators, &c. See the documentations for details.

Here is a demo. As you can see, the defaults are different for numprint and siunitx:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{numprint, SIunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\texttt{With numprint: } & Avogadro’s number is $ \mathrm{NA} =\numprint[mol^{-1}]{6.02214129e23} $\bigskip\\
\texttt{With SIunitx: } & Avogadro’s number is $ \mathrm{NA} =\SI{6.02214129e23}{\per\mole} $
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sure a few examples wouldn't go amiss. Currently, my money is on `siunitx`, as it offers a very wide range of functionalities for this, plus it is very actively and skilfully maintained. But I have yet to meet the `homonymous` package, googling didn't reveal much.

Comment: @moewe:You made me find the word seems to be an americanism. Doesn't seem to exist in British dictionaries. Anyway, `paronymous` is more appropriate.Other than that, I'll follow you suggestion and try  to add an illuminating example.

Comment: Oh! That was an embarrassing brain block on my part. Shame on me for not remembering my Greek lessons.... "Paronymous" is a word I haven't actually seen before (while "homonymous" should have been in the back of my mind), "of the same name" is probably a safer alternative for the likes of me.

Comment: Yes, but the package lacks the backslash (sounds like a good title for a detective novel, don't you think? ;o)), whence the paronymous (παρ̀α means ‘near’ if I remember well).

Comment: I will give you that, true. [Para can mean quite a lot](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=para&la=greek), I seem to remember, depending on the case, which reminds me of [this great little exchange](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5FRVvjGL2C0) (they even have someone homonymous to you there `:-D`).

Comment: Many of those small words in Greek can mean a lot  of things. That's one of the charms of the Greek  language. Even the aorist can mean many things, as far as I can remember.